# How do you calculate the expected average of random values rounded to integers?

Tags: math, random, language-agnostic

For example, consider following pseudocode:

```
round(random(0.3, 1.9))
```

With round rounding to nearest integer and random generating an uniform float between 0.3 and 1.9, the average of one million samples comes out to around `1.125`, as opposed to a naive average of `1.1`.

How can that number be derived algorithmically, without actually generating a few thousand numbers?

Hopefully this isn't too trivial of a question, but I just can't seem to figure out a simple solution.

Comment: does `random(0.3, 1.9)` return a random float between 0.3 and 1.9? How does round work? Does it round up at 0.5 or is it basically a `floor` function?

Comment: If `random` is uniform and `round` is to the next integer, then the average should be at `(0.2*0+1.0*1+0.4*2)/1.6=1.8/1.6= 1.125`.

Comment: @PatrickGünther Yes, it generates a random float between 0.3 and 1.9, and round is just rounding to nearest integer.

Comment: @LutzL Round rounds to the nearest integer. Sorry for not specifying, I thought it was clear.

Comment: Then please add more details on how you got to your average `0.84611`? How many samples did you use?

Comment: @LutzL 1,000,000 samples, exact Lua code used is `t=0; for i=1,1000000 do t = t + math.floor(math.random(0.3, 1.9)+0.5) end; print(t/1000000)`

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm doing floor(n+0.5), which is more or less equivalent to rounding to nearest integer, is it not?

Comment: I evaluated `mean(round(runif(1000000,0.3,1.9)))` in R and got `1.12389`, which meshes with the exact calculation of @LutzL .

Comment: @JohnColeman Yeah, I also just realized that Lua's math.random generates only integers when given parameters. I'll just delete this question silently, and thanks for the assistance folks.

Comment: The question itself is still somewhat interesting, and is tagged as language-agnostic, so there isn't any need to delete it. But, do what you want to.

Comment: Alright, fixed the question up a bit. Trying to figure a solution based off what @LutzL posted, but I'm really not very mathematically minded, and so far it eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly general solution:

First note that the problem can be reduced to that of computing the expected value of the floor of a random number in the range `(a,b)`, since the distribution of `round(X)` is the same as the distribution of `floor(Y)` where `Y = X + 0.5` (and `Y` is `U(a+0.5,b+0.5)` if `X` is `U(a,b)`). The advantage of reducing to floor is that we don't need to break into cases depending on `a` or `b` each rounding either up or down.

Let:

```
A = floor(a)
B = floor(b)
pA = (A + 1 - a)/(b-a)
pB = (b-B)/(b-a)
```

`pA` is the probability of `A`, `pB` is that of `B`. If integers other than `A` and `B` are possible then they are uniformly distributed in the interval `[A+1,B-1]`. The expected value of `floor(X)` given that it is neither `A` nor `B` is thus `(A+B)/2`. This conditional expectation would need to be weighted by the probability of such a value occurring. Putting this all together we have:

```
E(floor(X)) = pA*A + pB*B + (1-pA-pB)*(A+B)/2
```

There are a couple of subtleties. The above argument implicitly assumed that `(a,b)` contains at least 1 integer. If it doesn't, then the calculation of `pA` and `pB` aren't correct, but in that case `A = B = (A+B)/2` and the above formula still correctly returns this as the expected value.

The following is an R implementation. The first function implements the above formula and the second function shows how to reduce the rounding problem to it. If you don't know R, `<-` is the assignment operator and the last expression in a function definition is the returned value.

```
efloor <- function(a,b){
  A <- floor(a)
  B <- floor(b)
  pA <- (A+1-a)/(b-a)
  pB <- (b-B)/(b-a)
  pA*A + pB*B + (1-pA-pB)*(A+B)/2
}

eround <- function(a,b){
  efloor(a+0.5,b+0.5)
}
```

For example,

```
> eround(0.3,1.9)
[1] 1.125
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the comprehensive step-by-step answer, and final solution too. I was attempting something similar, but I've got a few details wrong and didn't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

On `[0.3,0.5)` you get the value `0`, on `[0.5,1.5)` the value `1` and on `[1.5,1.9)` the value `2`. As the random numbers are uniform, their probability is proportional to the interval length, with the full lengths being `1.9-0.3=1.6`. Thus the theoretical average is

```
0.2/1.6*0 + 1.0/1.6*1 + 0.4/1.6 * 2 = 1.8/1.6 = 1.125.
```

Comment: I think I'll be able to translate this into code, but if you don't mind, could you include a pseudocode function in your answer?